# iOS 12 VPN on demand not working in Readdle Documents

Tags: ios, vpn

On a iOS device (iPad) with iOS 12.1.4 installed I have successfully created a VPN tunnel to my home device (Fritzbox). I added a on demand configuration with a .mobileconfig file. This configuration should fire if I access the router or any internal device by calling i.e. server.fritz.box.

Here's the Action part from the mobileconfig:

```
<dict>
                            <key>Action</key>
                            <string>EvaluateConnection</string>
                            <key>ActionParameters</key>
                            <array>
                                <dict>
                                    <key>Domains</key>
                                    <array>
                                        <string>*.fritz.box</string>
                                        <string>fritz.box</string>
                                        <string>server.fritz.box</string>
                                    </array>
                                    <key>DomainAction</key>
                                    <string>ConnectIfNeeded</string>
                                </dict>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
```

On my internal DNS server I can see that there is a query to server.fritz.box, so I assume the configuration is ok.

This works fine if I call the URL within i.e. Safari, the tunnel will come up and the internal device page shows up.

I now want to use this for having a connection to my internal server with Readdle Documents so I created a configuration there with the URL smb://server.fritz.box. But the tunnel will never come up when I connect with Readdle documents.

If I bring the tunnel up by hand the Readdle Documents connection works fine.

Any idea what to do? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Readdle does not come with a real answer, seems they use their own networking calls. So there seems to be no real solution for this. Looking for alternative Apps now.

Answer (score 1):

Some applications utilise low level networking calls rather than Apple's network APIs. If this is the case then the app will fail to trigger the On-Demand VPN.

I expect that this is the case with Readdle Documents. I would recommend contacting their support team.